# Need help to execute sql scripts within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, error-handling, cursor, sql-scripts

Need help as how I can trap any errors related to executing a sql script in a stored procedure.

```
select sopScript 
from M_SopInsert 
where soptype = @soptype and sopnumbe = @sopnumbe and lnitmseq = @lnitmseq

If result_count > 0 //if result from above sql query is >0

exec sopScript //loop through the record set and execute sopscript for every record.
```

Note: sopscript here contains scripts like :

```
update customerMaster 
set custname='abc' 
where custid=100`"
```

Comment: Please check this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175920%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Are you asking for an example of how to create a cursor?

Comment: Please read this article on SQL cursors:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx

Comment: @davids: No, I was more interested in trapping any errors. Also let us say if the resultset has 5 rows (meaning I get 5 sopScripts) and if one sopScript fails, then I need to rollback all 5 and return with error.

Comment: He's looking for someone to do it for him.

Comment: It would be more helpful if your question title reflected the actual question (e.g How do I trap errors in a stored procedure) and if you demonstrate what you have actually done to try and solve it yourself.  In any case, please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Misread the question originally.

try using

```
declare @sopScript varchar(1000)

select sopScript 
into #ControlTbl
from M_SopInsert 
where soptype = @soptype and sopnumbe = @sopnumbe and lnitmseq = @lnitmseq


while exists (select * from #ControlTbl)
begin

    select top 1 @sopScript = sopScript
    from #ControlTbl

    begin try
        exec executesql @sopScript = sopScript 
    end try
    begin catch
        *do something*
    end catch

    delete from #ControlTbl
    where sopScript = @sopScript

end
```

Comment: I need to loop through the result set and then execute the sopscript for every record by capturing any errors. Also, I think you mentioned "top 1".

Comment: Thanks for the edit. How do I loop through 'n' records? Also I am more interested with examples of the catch and how I can control any errors. As sopScript is a sql script, I want to make sure if it s a good SQL script and when it gets executed, if there are any errors, I do something.

Comment: How you want to handle the error is up to you. Most log to a separate table or alert operator... etc.  Or are you trying to prevalidate the script before running?

Comment: I am more interested in trapping any errors. Also let us say if the resultset has 5 rows (meaning I get 5 sopScripts) and if one sopScript fails, then I need to rollback all 5 and return with error.

Comment: Talk about scope creep.

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. Also I didn't downvote your answer. I will be marking it answered shortly.

Comment: dont really care about the downvote. just didn't want to sit here all day answering questions. in the future, it would be more helpful if you can be more specific with your questions.  scope creep is a real problem in software development.. ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is how we do it:

Wrap the procedure steps in a `TRY` and `TRANSACTION`.  Then the individual executions in a `TRY`

```
DECLARE @lRollback bit=0
DECLARE @ErrTable TABLE (ErrNumber int,ErrSeverity int,ErrProc varchar(MAX),ErrLine int,ErrMsg varchar(MAX)) --table variable to collect errors.
BEGIN TRY  -- outside begin try
BEGIN TRANSACTION -- wrap transaction
....
   BEGIN TRY
   ...
   END TRY
   BEGIN CATCH
       {ERROR CATCH - see below}
   END CATCH
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SET @lRollback=1
    {ERROR CATCH - see below}       
    ROLLBACK
    BEGIN TRY
        INSERT INTO errorTable (importId,errNumber,errSeverity,errProc,errLine,errMsg) --This is the db default error collection table
        SELECT DISTINCT @importId,ErrNumber,ErrSeverity,ErrProc,ErrLine,ErrMsg FROM @ErrTable
    END TRY
    RETURN -1
END CATCH
```

Anytime you want to catch an error in the procedure, use this `ERROR CATCH`:

```
INSERT INTO @ErrTable (ErrNumber,ErrSeverity,ErrProc,ErrLine,ErrMsg)
SELECT
    ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
    ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
    ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
    ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
    ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;
```